# Edit translation text at runtime from server

Tags: android, localization, resources, string.xml

### Overview

**AFAIK** on Android you have twi ways to set the texts of your application:

- You can use `string.xml` with different locales
- You can download strings from server and set every label with a `setText(language.text)` but it will be a pain

The problem might sussist if you have to change a text of your published application without re-publishing it; for example if you want to change for a specific translation a small text without any functionality change. (ie: you might notice that you wrote "Take picure" instead of "Take picture").

### Library

[i18next](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-android) is a good library to manage translations dinamically from server, but you still have to add the text for each label you got.

### So, my question is

Still AFAIK, there is no way to do it natively, but is there a low level library or a workaround that allows to replace a string in your `string.xml` with some downloaded text?

Another option could be to make our label text to point instead of at `@string/myValue` to something like `@myresource.pathtovalue`.

Honestly I think this could be an huge improvement for application, is there something useful?

Comment: I'm looking for the same, did you find a solution?

Comment: @Day unfortunatly no, we gave up on that and started working on another task.. We will probably get back on this soon, if I find a solution I will write here ^^; if someone can answer this question I will be really glad :)

Comment: I'll try using that Restring library as suggested [here](https://medium.com/@hamidgh/dynamically-change-bundled-strings-a24b97bfd306). Will post an answer if I have positive results